# Find CDF of $\max(X_1,X_2)$

Tags: probability

We have 2 bags, each one contains two white balls and one black. We take 2 balls from each bag. Let $X_1$ - number of white balls that we got from first bag, $X_2$ - from second. Find CDF of variable $Z=\max(X_1,X_2)$.

$F_Z\left(t\right)=\mathbb{P}\left(Z\le t \right)=\mathbb{P}\left(\max\left(X_1,X_2 \right)\le t \right)=?$

And what next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Write out the support of the random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$.  What values can these random variables admit?
2. What are the respective probabilities of observing each outcome in the support?
3. Are $X_1$ and $X_2$ independent random variables?  Why or why not?
4. What are the probabilities of observing the **joint** outcomes $(X_1, X_2) = (x_1, x_2)$?
5. For each joint outcome $(x_1, x_2)$, what is the value of $z = \max(x_1, x_2)$ and what is the probability $\Pr[Z = z]$?
6. What is the cumulative probability $\Pr[Z \le z]$ based on your calculation of the probability mass function in step (5)?

Comment: 1. We can get 0,1 or 2 balls
  2. $\mathbb{P}(X_i = 0)=0$,  $\mathbb{P}(X_i = 1)=3\cdot\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{2}{3}$,  $\mathbb{P}(X_i = 2)=3\cdot\frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{2}{3}$
  3. Yes, they are independent since getting ball from 1 bag doesn't affect another bag
  4. If $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent, then $\mathbb{P}(X_1=m)\cdot\mathbb{P}(X_2=n)=\mathbb{P}(X_1=m \text{ and } X_2=n)$
   5. $z=x_1$ for $x_1>x_2$ and $z=x_2$ for $x2>x_1$ and $z=x_1=x_2$ for $x_1=x_2$

Comment: As for the rest, what is the probability $Pr[Z=z]$, hmm, I am really not sure. Maybe $Pr[Z=z]=Pr(Z=\max(x_1,x_2))=Pr\left(Z=x_1 \text{ and } x_1>x_2\right) + Pr\left(Z=x_2 \text{ and } x_2 > x_1 \right) + Pr\left(Z=x_i \text{ and } x_1=x_2 \right)  $?